# Webpack production build generating no build output and almost no terminal log messages

Tags: npm, webpack, package.json, production, webpack-production

Im creating my own webpack starter template and in my recent tuning I've somehow stopped the build version from working but I have no idea what's wrong or how to debug it as there no obvious error messages or such.

In my package.json I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-serve --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
```

My **start** script runs well. The **build** Script is not working.

The build script does this in the terminal.

```
$ npm run build

> webpack-tailwind-starter-template@1.0.0 build /Users/richiekhoo/projects/webpack-tailwind-starter-template
> webpack --config webpack.prod.js
> 
> and nothing more...
```

Debug Attemp #1
Does webpack from the CLI work?

I ran these:

$ webpack
$ webpack -v
$ webpack --version

I didn't get a 'command not found' instead the command executed provided no output and exited.

Is the issue that webpack is not running properly?

I wondered is it enough to have webpack in package.json or do I need it installed globally locally and via npm as a standalone package?

---

Lost as to how to work out what's wrong. Please help.

Here's the code including my webpack config files:

https://github.com/demingfactor/webpack-tailwind-starter-template

Answer (score 0):

I'm running asdf and it seems there are some issues with how asdf interacts with npm.

I fixed my issue by running these commands (any of them individually could have been the fix).

```
$ asdf plugin-update --all

$ asdf update

$ npm i npm
```

I found the solutions here in the last few entries on the thread - https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/162